# Вызов функции из dll которая возвращает пользовательскую структуру данных написанной на Delphi из Python

Tags: python, delphi, dll, ctypes

Есть например такая функция:

```
function GetStateTerminal(var vStateTerminal: TStateTerminal): Integer; stdcall;

type TStateTerminal: 
        VersionDLL: array[0..25] of char
        isActivePinPad: Byte
        ComPortPinPad: array[0..9] of char
        SystemsData: array[1..3] of TListSystemsData
           type TListSystemsData:
                isLicenze: Byte
                isLoadKeys: Byte
                isLoadCfg: Byte
                isOnLine: Byte
                NumShift: Integer
                DateTimeShift: array[0..11] of char
                isOpenShift: Byte
                isActive: Byte
```

Возвращаемый тип значения PChar указатель на строку.

Как получить значение?

Comment: Уточните объявление типов с учётом синтаксиса Delphi. Какая версия Delphi используется для компиляции dll? И если функция `GetStateTerminal` возвращает `PChar`, то почему в объявлении у вас написано `Integer`?

Comment: У меня есть описание для этой dll, там так указано. Не знаю правильно ли, но сделал так: создал имя_класса(Structure), в _fields_ описал поля, а дальше воспользовался Вашим ответом на мой предыдущий вопрос.

Comment: А кроме официальной документации есть может статьи с хорошими примерами? Или более понятное описание алгоритма работы особенно с библиотеками написанными на delphi?

Comment: В зависимости от версии Delphi, тип Char может быть либо 1, либо 2 байта (AnsiChar или WideChar). Также, в зависимости от объявления структуры, поля в ней могут быть выровнены по 4, 8 байт или выравнивание может быть вовсе отключено. Без этой информации можно только гадать, какой же на самом деле вид у этой структуры. А по поводу статей - ищите примеры на Си. Всю специфику именно Delphi я вам привёл выше, остальное работает аналогично.

Comment: Хотя, официальной документации более чем достаточно. Если до завтрашнего вечера никто не даст ответ или вы сами не разберётесь, дам свой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вам не известно в какой версии Delphi и с какими настройками компилировалась та dll, то предположим, что под `Char` имеется в виду `AnsiChar` и что выравнивание полей у записей дефолтное (по границе 8 байт).

Если окажется, что строки обрезаются (т.е. в dll они на самом деле являются юникодными строками, т.е. `WideChar`), то замените в описаниях структур тип `c_char` на `c_wchar` и результат функции на `c_wchar_p`.

А если окажется, что числовые поля выдают не то, или вдруг появится Access Violation, то скорее всего проблема с выравниванием полей - замените значение `_pack_` в описаниях структур на 1 (если структуры на самом деле являются упакованными) или на 2, 4.

```
_dll = ctypes.windll.test
GetStateTerminal = _dll.GetStateTerminal

class TListSystemsData(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 8 # выравнивание полей. Допустимые значения: 1, 2, 4, 8
    _fields_ = [("isLicenze", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("isLoadKeys", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("isLoadCfg", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("isOnLine", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("NumShift", ctypes.c_int32),
                ("DateTimeShift", ctypes.c_char*12),
                ("isOpenShift", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("isActive", ctypes.c_ubyte)]

class TStateTerminal(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 8
    _fields_ = [("VersionDLL", ctypes.c_char*26),
                ("isActivePinPad", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("ComPortPinPad", ctypes.c_char*10),
                ("SystemsData", TListSystemsData*3)]

GetStateTerminal.argtype = ctypes.POINTER(TStateTerminal)
GetStateTerminal.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

vStateTerminal = TStateTerminal() # создание структуры

# инициализация полей, если нужно
vStateTerminal.VersionDLL = 'xxx'
vStateTerminal.isActivePinPad = 5
vStateTerminal.SystemsData[0].isActive = 1

# вызов функции
Result = GetStateTerminal(ctypes.byref(vStateTerminal))

# печать результата
print(Result)

print(vStateTerminal.VersionDLL)
print(vStateTerminal.isActivePinPad)
print(vStateTerminal.ComPortPinPad)

for SystemsData in vStateTerminal.SystemsData:
    print(SystemsData.DateTimeShift)
    print(SystemsData.NumShift)
```

Инициализацию полей перед вызовом функции скорее всего делать не нужно и что-то мне подсказывает, что параметр на самом деле должен быть объявлен как `out`, но это уже вопрос к разработчику dll.